# Why was sleep_ms() deprecated?

Tags: rust

I know there is a function [`sleep()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) that is more flexible, as it accepts a [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html) as a parameter. Obviously, in many cases that could be more convenient. But from my personal experience with other languages, most of the time I need to put a thread to sleep for milliseconds or seconds, rather than hours or days. So in most cases something like this:

```
thread::sleep_ms(500);
```

would be much more convenient than this:

```
use std::time::Duration;
thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(500));
```

This question isn't about which of the two functions is *better*. I personally think there is room for both, but that is subjective, of course.

My question is, was there any special, non-obvious reason for the deprecation of `sleep_ms()`? I tried to find info on the topic, but to no avail.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/51610 <- some discussion in here

Comment: [@alexcrichton's comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/51610#issuecomment-401223638) in the issue to which @dratenik refers particularly answers the question of "why".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to dratenik's and eggyal's comments, I believe it is correct to summarize that the main reason for deprecating `sleep_ms()` is that the Rust core devs believe the right way to go should be to work on adding less verbose ways to pass a `Duration` value.

Here is what is comming:

```
#![feature(duration_constants)]

use std::time::Duration;
thread::sleep(2 * Duration::SECOND);
```